# Find the proportion of even numbers per row

Tags: r

I have a matrix containing 5 columns and 20 rows. For each row, I want to find the proportion of even numbers that row has and write it per row. My trouble is finding the proportion of even numbers.

So here is a part of the output:

```
        1   2   3   4   5
 [1,]   6   5   1   2   5

x <- apply(matrix, 1, length(matrix %% 2 == 0)/5)

matrix <- cbind(matrix, x)
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Sure, this is what I have.

Comment: Yes. Just provided. See the initial post. I don't know how to try this one.

Comment: `m <- matrix(rpois(20 * 5, 2), 20); rowSums(m %% 2 == 0) / ncol(m)`

Comment: I don't know how is this going to help. For example, if you see the first vector, I have 2 even numbers 6 and 2. So I want to add another column stating the percentage of even numbers. i.e. 0.4. How do I do that?

Comment: `rowMeans(m %% 2 ==0)`

Comment: Within the apply function?

Comment: With matrices, `cbind(m, rowSums(m %% 2 == 0) / ncol(m))`, though if you're using columns like that you should probably switch to data frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look in `?"%%"`. Here an example:

```
## reproducible example 
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(
  sample(1:10,5*20,replace = TRUE),
  nrow = 20, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)
## 1- convert matrix to a logical one using %% 
## 2- compute occurrence of TRUE value using the vectorised rowSums
## 3- divide by the number of column to convert occurrence to proportions 
rowSums(mat %% 2 ==0)/ncol(mat)
```

Comment: Maybe `rowMeans` would be more straightforward here.

Comment: @Imo yes why not.

Comment: I need the proportions of even numbers. rowMeans won't give me proportions. Here is what I have.

Comment: OK. Got it. It was rowSums and not rowMeans. Because I want to find the proportions. I changed rowMeans to rowSums and got it. Thanks so much.

Comment: @stat77 I am not sure you understand the solution.  why not to take the time to read my code comments?

Comment: @agstudy - yes. I saw the comments and did just that and got it. Thanks so much. Sorry, I saw rowMeans up there somewhere so I was refering to that.

Comment: Now what if I want to find the variance instead of proportion? I mean variance of each row.

Comment: @stat77 At some point you have to switch to `apply`, e.g. for the variance of each row, `apply(m, 1, var)`

Comment: @alistaire Perfect! Thanks. That's what I was missing. Thanks again.